# has_many/has_one :through makes N+1 queries in some cases, use delegate instead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, rails-activerecord

While diagnosing N+1 query issue I noticed that ActiveRecord has_one/has_many :through associations when chained together are ignoring includes.

Example code (my case was with our models):

```
class Post  < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :user
   has_one :badge, through: :user
end


class User  < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :badge
 end

 class Badge  < ActiveRecord::Base

 end
```

Going through the associations does not do additional queries other than the includes

```
post = Post.include(:user => :badge)
post.user.badge
```

But trying to use the through:

```
post = Post.include(:user => :badge)
post.badge
```

makes another LIMIT 1 query. Which would result in N+1 in a loop.

To solve this I thought to replace all has_one/many :through, with delegates. Is there any advantage to the has_many/one :through option (for when there are no conditions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that includes(:user => :badge) follows the Post.user association and then the User.badge association, so when you follow the single Post.badge association Rails is ignoring the includes since you've set it up for different associations.

That is, even though it's the same path, they are different associations.

Just includes(:badge) would work better.

Comment: (I am working with @mrbaker) Yeah, but I will want to do post.user at other parts of the code. has_one :through can be a bit smarter to check if it exists before querying. 

Also this does not answer the question if delegate has any advantages

Comment: Given delegate is at its heart just a simple method call, it may well work better for you in this case. I'm not sure if there's any gotchas here (besides the usual one of deciding what to do if you get nil in the middle), but it's definitely worth a try.

Part of the benefit of through associations is handling the case where you're following -> many -> one or -> many -> many without convoluted map/flattening logic, which doesn't really apply here.

Comment: Also maybe includes(:badge, :user => :badge).

Answer (score 1):

I think this code may work better for you.

```
post = Post.includes(:user => [:badge])
```